# Use SpannableString in Android Home Screen widgets?

Tags: android, widget, spannablestring

Can I use `SpannableStrings` in a widget's textView? I tried and all it rendered was plain text. I don't know if it is something I'm doing wrong (most likely), or if it just isn't possible for some reason.

Here's the code I'm using (nothing special really...)

```
 public static void updateWidgetState(Context paramContext, String paramString, Integer appWidgetId) {

    SpannableString majorLabel = new SpannableString("");
    SpannableString minorLabel = new SpannableString("");
    if (position > -1) {
        majorLabel = GetParsedMajorLabel(paramContext);
        minorLabel = GetParsedMinorLabel(paramContext);
    }
    RemoteViews localRemoteViews = buildUpdate(paramContext, paramString, appWidgetId);
    localRemoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.majorlabel, majorLabel);
    localRemoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.minorlabel, minorLabel);
 }
```

Comment: Can you show your code where you get the `Spanned` object and how you put it into the `RemoteViews`?

Comment: code added, but I don't think it will help much.

Comment: Have you tried a simpler scenario, such as using `Html.fromHtml()` to create the `Spanned` object out of some HTML snippet, in case the problem lies in your `GetParsed...Label()` methods?

Comment: I use that same code to display the text in other places in my app (non-widget), and it seems to be working fine there. But I will give fromHtml a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to display formatted text in a `TextView`, use [`fromHtml`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: fromHtml just returns a Spannable object, so I don't think it will be any different than using SpannableString. But the fact that you are suggesting it makes me think that it indeed can be possible so I must be goobering it up somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
String urlink = "http://www.google.com";
String link = "<a href=\"+urlink+ >link</a>"; 
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(link));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily set Spannable String in widget. what I did is I used `SpannableStringBuilder`  as set it to remoteView's `textView`.

```
  views.setTextViewText(R.id.rsTV, WidgetUtils.setPriceSpannableHomeScreenString(currentUserBalance.balance, context))


fun setPriceSpannableHomeScreenString(price: String, context: Context?): SpannableStringBuilder {

    val builder = SpannableStringBuilder()

    if (AppClass.hasValue(price) && context != null) {

        val st = StringTokenizer(price.trim { it <= ' ' }, ".") //pass dot as delimeter

        val balanceArrayList = ArrayList<String>()

        //iterate through tokens

        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            balanceArrayList.add(st.nextToken("."))
        }

        val priceRsText = context.getString(R.string.rs)
        var priceBeforeDecimal = ""
        var priceAfterDecimal = ""

        if (balanceArrayList.size > 0) {

            if (balanceArrayList.size > 0 && balanceArrayList.get(0) != null) {
                priceBeforeDecimal = balanceArrayList.get(0)
            }

            if (balanceArrayList.size >= 2 && balanceArrayList.get(1) != null) {
                priceAfterDecimal = balanceArrayList.get(1)
            }

        }

        val firstValue = "$priceRsText.$priceBeforeDecimal."

        val lastValue = priceAfterDecimal


        val txtSpannable = SpannableString(firstValue)
        val boldSpan = StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)
        txtSpannable.setSpan(RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, firstValue.length, 0) // set size
        txtSpannable.setSpan(boldSpan, 0, firstValue.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        builder.append(txtSpannable)
        builder.append(lastValue)
        // priceSpannableTextView.setText(builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)

        return builder
    }

    return builder
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2020 Html.fromHtml is deprecated in Android N

Use `HtmlCompat.fromHtml` for better compatibility

Example setting Bold text with HTML

```
 setTextViewText(
                  R.id.wind, HtmlCompat.fromHtml(
                            "<b>Wind:</b>"+ windSpeedKmh+"<br/>"+
                            "<b>Direction:</b>" +windDirection
                       , HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
                    )
```