# NullPointerException thrown while creating SpannableString

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

I am trying to create a textview whose text is partially underlined using a spannableString but I'm getting a nullpointerexception when I try to do that. Here's my code:

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHelp);
    SpannableString content = new SpannableString("Underlined text");
    content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
    tv.setText(content+"non-underlined text"); //exception is thrown here
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: try saving the `UnderlineSpan` as a separate var, and also the length. if one of them is `null` you'll know where the problem is.

Comment: Your TextView is null. Are you sure you have called setContentView(), and that you have a textview with the id of tvHelp?

Comment: Use this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887574/android-use-spannablestring-in-widgets

Comment: Oh ok thank you, sorry that was my bad. Careless mistakes...

Answer (score 1):

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHelp);
SpannableString content = new SpannableString("Underlined text");
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
tv.setText(content+"non-underlined text"); //exception is thrown here
```

Write the above code after

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
and
setContentView("Your Layout");
```

Comment: No actually my textview was null thanks for your help though.