# Spannable string with image not working with push notification

Tags: android, push-notification

I am trying to use spannable string with image on push notification. It is not working. Actually I want to show emoticon on push notification like wattsapp. If I am using simple spannable string it is working. The same spannable string with image is working fine with textview.

For this I have also tried custom push notification but did not get success.

My code is as follows :-

**MainActivity.class**

```
   package com.example.tt.notificationtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.style.BackgroundColorSpan;
import android.text.style.ImageSpan;
import android.text.style.RelativeSizeSpan;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnNotification;
    TextView txtMsg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
        btnNotification = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNotification);
        btnNotification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Notify("Testing", "msg");
                Notify2();
            }
        });
    }

    private void Notify2(){
        int icon = R.drawable.asdf;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "Custom Notification", when);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.asdf);

        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("abcd");
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.asdf);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
        ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
        ss.setSpan(span, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Custom notification");
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, ss);
        notification.contentView = contentView;

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR; //Do not clear the notification
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; // LED
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; //Vibration
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; // Sound

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }

    private void Notify(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage){

        //This is working

//        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Large\n\n" );   // index 103 - 112
//        ss.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.CYAN), 0, 5, 0);



        //this is not working
        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("abcd");
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.asdf);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
        ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
        ss.setSpan(span, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        txtMsg.setText(ss);

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                i,
                0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setContentText(ss)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.asdf)
//                .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
//                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(ss))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pi)
                .build();

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(2, notification);
    }

}
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.tt.notificationtest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Me"
        android:id="@+id/btnNotification"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**custom_notification.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: Not till right now. I got some answers below but not satisfied with these answers.

Comment: @AnandKumarJha have you gotten a solution yet?

Comment: Not till right now

Answer (score 3):

This is the only way I got it working:

Spanned mssg;
mssg = Html.fromHtml(URLDecoder.decode("%F0%9F%98%82"));

It may vary depending on how do you receive your text, in my case i'm sending the emojicons using unicode to a GCM server and I don't have to worry about the URLDecoder, but if I receive a message sent from a emojicon PHP library and not from an android device the only way to show it properly was with the URLDecoder.

So if you're working with GCM it should be working with just

Spanned mssg;
mssg = Html.fromHtml(intent.getStringExtra("message"));

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I want to show custom image not unicode.

Comment: @AnandKumarJha https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887574/android-use-spannablestring-in-widgets this answer will solve your problem without using HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Mixpanel have working solution for sending emoticons in push notifications. You can find description [here](https://mixpanel.com/help/questions/articles/how-do-i-send-custom-parameters-like-emoji-in-my-push-notifications)

Comment: {"mp_message": "High Five, bro \u270B"} this is also using unicode "\u270B" I want to insert custom image.

Comment: I dont understand, you want to put custom image inside of text? In notification you only can put 3 pictures (as i know) large icon of the left, small icon on the right and maybe big image at the bottom, but in text you can use only string value (including emoticons from UTF-8)

Comment: By using unicode it can be done. Actually, I have manage my custom emoticon in chat that is working fine but it is not working in push notification. For example I am getting "):" and converting it to its respective image to show string as emoti but in string it showing as "):"..

Answer (score 2):

You are using deprecated code here

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "Custom Notification", when);
```

[image]

Instead use your RemoteView like `NotificationBuilder.sentContent(remoteView)`

Take a look at this [Custom Notification](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-custom-notification-tutorial/) example